# Swift Firebase downloadURL returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have updated my firebase code and I have got my data to save to the database and save to the storage, yet my downloadURL returns nil. I am not sure why my downloadURL would return nil since everything is saving correctly. Could be so obvious I am overlooking it... it happens lol

```
let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Businesses")
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")
    let postID = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().key
    photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            // store downloadURL
            photoRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {

                    let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString
                    print(downloadURL)
                    print("HERE#####################################")
                    let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "download_url": downloadURL, "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

                    // store downloadURL at database
                    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                    let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
                    path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error saving post in db")
                        } else {
                            // reset caption field
                            self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                            // reset placeholder image
                            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            let viewConrolller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                            self.present(viewConrolller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**Easy Mistake**

I was not accessing the actual image which is why it was returning nil

```
 photoRef.child("\(imageName)").downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is flawed in the completion handler of `photoRef.downloadURL`, you try using `downloadURL` in case `error` had a value, meaning that there was a networking error.

```
photoRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
    if let downloadURL = url, error == nil {...
```

Comment: Using this code made me take a step back because now it is saying that the path in firebase does not exist. When I revert back to the code above everything saves correctly yet downloadURL is still nil

Comment: "Object posts/wqyMJTs438XsJWq13ciAYyzs9Am2/wqyMJTs438XsJWq13ciAYyzs9Am2 does not exist." this is the print out I get when I use your code

Comment: @LukasBimba that if statement was definitely incorrect, just take a moment to actually think about what yours was doing. It was trying to process the `downloadURL` in case `error != nil`, which means that the network request failed, so `downloadURL` cannot be anything other than `nil`. If you see more issues that means there's other flaws in your logic, I'll look into those as well.

Comment: Im using the code you have provided to me. I appreciate the help

Comment: I had figured it out, I just was not accessing the actual image

Answer (score 0):

The ref.downloadURL completion handler will not be executed until do this trick:

Just fix 'FirebaseInstanceID' to version '2.0.0' in the podfile, putData method will be executed. It look like this in podfile: 
        pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

I'm using Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5, the trick still works